# System not booting after RAM upgrade

Tags: memory, bios

I have purchased an EVM DDR2 1GB 800 RAM (EVMP1G800U68D) today and found that my PC is not booting with the new RAM. I already have an APACER PC2-6400 1 GB RAM installed.

When I insert only my old RAM the PC is fine. The problem appears only with the new EVM RAM. With both RAMs mixed or the new RAM alone the fans start and CPU lights are on but the monitor power light just blinks. There were no beeps or signals that is heard during a faulty installation of RAM.

See below for my old RAM details by CPU-Z

[image: screenshot of old RAM details]

The new RAM I bought is from [Flipcart](http://www.flipkart.com/evm-ddr2-1-gb-pc-ram-evmp1g667u68c-evmp1g667u88d-evmp1g800u68d/p/itmdnymmjcqhjfgr); notice I got the EVMP1G800U68D one.

My motherboard is Intel D102GGC2, and CPU is Intel Pentium D 2.8GHz**

Comment: What is your computer model, or motherboard model ?

Comment: Yes !! I have edited the question including pc details

Comment: No!! The capslock, numlock and scrolllock lights are not blinking.. But i dont think that makes a hardware error according to MS upto 800MHz is supported but will be underclocked... Isn't that so?

Comment: so what will be the problem causing....will it be power issue??

Comment: really no help :(

Comment: so could you explain that much more... in bios i could just see memory speed 800 but im afraid i couldnt make changes in that..

Comment: Yes i found that in BIOS chipset it was set to automatic and i changed it to manual and changed the speed to 667 and **VOILA!!** it started working....

Comment: now i am using 2gb ram to make this comment :) Thank You USER2196728 for the support

Comment: And i have something else to ask.... will the clock speed matter in both ram... because BIOS shows 5-5-5-18 for old and 6-6-6-24 for new. Is that a problem...

Comment: I've clean comments, you should do the same. I've made an answer that resumes all comments

Comment: @c0deFreak 5-5-18 vs 6-6-6-24  If you have both sets installed you must use the slower 6-6-6-24 timings to make both sets happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your new RAM does not support SPD (i cannot find this infos in the specs).

Your motherboard specs regarding SPD :

> the board should be populated with DIMMs that support the Serial
>   Presence Detect (SPD) data structure. This allows the BIOS to read the
>   SPD data and program the chipset to accurately configure memory
>   settings for optimum performance. If non-SPD memory is installed, the
>   BIOS will attempt to correctly configure the memory settings, but
>   performance and reliability may be impacted or the DIMMs may not
>   function under the determined frequency

You can check your BIOS to see if you can set the RAM speed.

If yes, set it accordingly to your RAM speed : 667Mhz in your case.

> And i have something else to ask.... will the clock speed matter in
>   both ram... because BIOS shows 5-5-5-18 for old and 6-6-6-24 for new.
>   Is that a problem...

This is Latency related. It is a bit tricky :

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SDRAM_latency
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR2_SDRAM
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAS_latency

i admit i don't really know.

Regarding specs for your new RAM, CAS Latency is `5-6-7-8-9-10-11`, and regarding previous links, for DDR2 667/PC2-5300 you can try to adjust to `5-5-5-15`.